# Intellij Idea Scala worksheet forward reference

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

there is an example of scala worksheet which compiles and executes in Eclipse but doesn't compile in Intellij Idea (version 12.0.6 with scala plugin 0.22.302).

```
object trees {

  trait Tree

  case class Node(left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree

  case class Leaf(value: Int) extends Tree

  def treeSum(t: Tree): Int = t match {
    case n: Node => nodeSum(n)
    case l: Leaf => leafSum(l)
  }

  def nodeSum(n: Node): Int = {
    treeSum(n.left) + treeSum(n.right)
  }

  def leafSum(l: Leaf): Int = {
    l.value
  }

  val tree = new Node(Leaf(5), Leaf(1))
  treeSum(tree) 
}
```

the problem with Idea is that nodeSum is defined after it is used.

```
 > <console>:13: error: not found: value nodeSum
 case n: Node => nodeSum(n)
```

Is it correct behaviour? I know that I can inline nodeSum and leafSum bodies right to the match body. But are there any other approaches to bypass this in Idea? And why does it work in Eclipse?

Comment: I had the same issue. It seems to me IntelliJ's support to Scala and Play! Framework is really bad